# Serialization Of Polymorphic Array Failing

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have enabled Polymorphic serialization support by adding annotations on the base class. I am able to seriazlize an individual object successfully and it is writing the type information as part of serialized data. However, the same is not happening if I store the objects in a list and serialize it.

It seems this issue was fixed in 1.6.3 (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-362)

I am using Jackson 2.3.2 and still facing the issue.

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Code:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({@Type(value = Derived.class, name = "derived")})
public abstract class Base {

}

public class Derived extends Base {

    private String field;

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new  ObjectMapper();
        Derived d = new Derived();
        d.setField("Name");
        Base b = d;
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(b));
        List<Base> list = new ArrayList<Base>();
        list.add(d);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(list));
    }
}
```

Output:
{"type":"derived","field":"Name"}
[{"field":"Name"}]

Thanks,
Praveen

Comment: You can certainly serialize and deserialize a list of objects polymorphically with Jackson. Can you share your code where you serialize/attempt to deserialize these objects?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/699

This is due to Java type erasure: when serializing a List, all Jackson see as a type is List (roughly equivalent to List). And since type Object does not have polymorphic type information (annotation), none will be written.
So this is not a bug in Jackson, but an unfortunate feature of Java Type Erasure.
It does not apply to arrays, since they retain element type information (arrays are not generic; arrays of different types are different classes, whereas generic typing is mostly compile-time syntactic sugar).

There are three main ways to deal with this:

```
pass full generic type using TypeReference (ObjectMapper has method like mapper.writerFor(new TypeReference<List<Base>>() { }).writeValue(....)
Sub-class List to something like public class BaseList extends ArrayList<Base>() { }, and pass that: this type WILL retain type information
Avoid using root-level List and Maps
```

I personally recommend doing (3), since this avoids all related problems with type erasure.
In my opinion JSON root value should always be a JSON Object, usually serialized to/from POJO.

Approach (2) will however work, and this is what most users do. It does require use of an additional helper class.

Approach (1) may or may not work; problem being that forcing type information does also affect actual value serialization. So while it will add type id, it may result in some properties not being serialized.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by using arrays, instead of list (since list does type erasure):

for example, your above test-case could be written as:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new  ObjectMapper();
        Derived d = new Derived();
        d.setField("Name");
        Base b = d;
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(b));
        List<Base> list = new ArrayList<Base>();
        list.add(d);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(
                      list.toArray(new Base[list.size]) // <--This Part
            ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with object array. Object[] doesn't carry type information but individual objects do. It's a shame that jackson doesn't handle that automatically.

Two possible solutions:
1. Typed array serialization works just fine:

```
Base[] myArray = Base[]{d};
mapper.writeValueAsString(myArray)
```

this will actually produce expected result as Base[] has type information.

2. I solved that my issue with custom serializer.

Serializer:

```
public class ObjectArraySerializer extends StdSerializer<Object[]> {
  public ObjectArraySerializer(final Class<Object[]> vc) {
    super(vc);
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(
      final Object[] data,
      final JsonGenerator gen,
      final SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    gen.writeStartArray();
    for (Object obj : data) {
      gen.writeObject(obj);
    }
    gen.writeEndArray();
  }
}
```

ObjectMapper configuration:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(
    Object[].class,
    new ObjectArraySerializer(Object[].class));
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```